# MySQL/Maria build view matching abbreviations to full description

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, view, mariadb

First, i do not control the data i'm managing. It comes in from a client in a spreadsheet & i'm making what i can of it. i'm actually taking a tangled mess & trying to normalize it as best i can.

i'm using MariaDB 5.5.30, InnoDB table formats.

One of my project requirements calls for an item description, which is comprised of "standard" abbreviations (at least within their company), to be presented in search results. Users may not know all the abbreviation definitions, so their initial idea was a separate search box to look up an abbreviation. Instead, i'd like to let the user hover/click on abbreviations in-line and see a tool-tip of the definition.

i know this would involve a view of some kind that matches abbreviations within the description to the abbreviations table to get the definitions. i'm also aware of the overhead this potentially creates.

i'm looking for suggestions for a relatively efficient way to do this (view, routine, etc.). Even if it means building a static table tying the item to records providing the definitions...

```
|          ITEMS                       |
|--------------------------------------|
| Item ID | Desc                       |
|--------------------------------------|
|       1 | CHOC CONG DR DRP 18" 25ct. |
|--------------------------------------|

|       ABBREVIATIONS              |
|----------------------------------|
| Abbr ID | Abbr | Definition      |
|----------------------------------|
|       1 | CHOC | Chocolate       |
|       2 | CONG | Congestion      |
|       3 | DR   | Delayed-Release |
|       4 | DRP  | Drops           |
|----------------------------------|
```

Abbreviations can appear in the Item Description in almost any combination. Only the pieces of the description matching an abbreviation would have a tooltip. Unfortunately, some abbreviations are multiple words and others are shorter than 4 characters.

If doing this would be painful for performance, i'm willing to go back to their original idea. But in the interest of a unified interface, i thought this would be nice.

Any (constructive) suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was put on the back-burner for a few months, but i got back around to toying with this...

```
SELECT ITEMS.ID, ITEMS.Desc, ABBRS.Abbr, ABBRS.Definition
FROM ITEMS
LEFT JOIN ABBREVIATIONS ABBRS ON ITEMS.Desc 
  LIKE REGEXP CONCAT('.*[[:<:]]', ABBRS.Abbr, '[[:>:]].*');
```

This produces the Item Description over several records, each with a matching Abbreviation & Definition:

```
| RESULTS                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| ID | Desc                       | Abbr | Definition      |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 | CHOC CONG DR DRP 18" 25ct. | CHOC | Chocolate       |
|  1 | CHOC CONG DR DRP 18" 25ct. | CONG | Chocolate       |
|  1 | CHOC CONG DR DRP 18" 25ct. | DR   | Delayed-Release |
|  1 | CHOC CONG DR DRP 18" 25ct. | DRP  | Drops           |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

The `REGEXP` with word-boundary markers usage makes sure that single-letter abbreviations don't match partial-words in the Description.

From there i can place an actionable element around the substring of the Description matching the Abbreviation so they can see the Definition.

Ugh.